# GtkClutter Actor signals not firing

Tags: gtk, pygtk, clutter, pygobject

I'm trying to write an app using GtkClutter but I can't get  the actors to fire signals. Here is a sample

```py
from gi.repository import GtkClutter, Clutter, Gtk, Gdk

GtkClutter.init([])

class MyCanvas(GtkClutter.Embed):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyCanvas'

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCanvas, self).__init__()

        self.stage = self.get_stage()

        self.rect = MyRect()
        self.stage.connect('key-press-event', self.key_press) # This Works!
        self.stage.add_actor(self.rect)
        self.rect.set_position(10, 10)

        self.show_all()

    def key_press(self, widget, event):
        print widget, event


class MyRect(Clutter.Rectangle):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyRect'

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRect, self).__init__()
        self.set_color(Clutter.Color.new(255, 255, 255, 0))
        self.set_border_color(Clutter.Color.new(255, 255, 255, 255))
        self.set_border_width(1)
        self.set_size(200, 200)

        self.set_reactive(True)

    # None of the following callbacks work
    # Not even if I explicitly connect signals like 
    # self.connect('button-press-event', self.on_button_press)

    def do_button_press_event(self, event):
        print event

    def do_motion_event(self, event):
        print event


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyWindow'

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.canvas = AnnotateCanvas()
        self.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON1_MOTION_MASK)
        self.set_size_request(500, 500)

        vbox_main = Gtk.VBox()
        scrolledwin = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwin.add_with_viewport(self.canvas)
        vbox_main.pack_end(scrolledwin, True, True, 0)
        self.add(vbox_main)

    def run(self):
        self.show_all()
        self.loop = GObject.MainLoop()
        self.loop.run()


app = MyWindow()
app.run()
```

All signals are working fine but mouse signals like 'button-press' and 'motion' are not firing on the clutter actor (MyRect/MyCanvas.stage) object. Not even if I give up sub-classing and do everything with stock classes.

**I suppose GtkWindow or GtkEmbed is not allowing mouse events to propagate to ClutterStage**

Simplified Version

```py
from gi.repository import GObject, GtkClutter, Clutter, Gtk

GtkClutter.init([])

def pressed(widget, event):
    print widget, event

w = Gtk.Window()
e = GtkClutter.Embed.new()
e.set_size_request(500, 500)
w.add(e)

s = e.get_stage()
s.set_color(Clutter.Color.new(0,0,0,0))
s.set_size(500, 500)

r = Clutter.Rectangle()
r.set_color(Clutter.Color.new(255,255,255,255))
r.set_size(200,200)
r.set_position(0,0)
r.set_reactive(True)
s.add_actor(r)

s.connect('button-press-event', pressed)
# r.connect('button-press-event', pressed)
w.show_all()
GObject.MainLoop().run()
```

*Stage and actors fire mouse signals when using just Clutter. It just doesn't work when embedding the stage into a GtkWindow using GtkClutter.Embed*

**Update**

When I try to run the example from http://www.openismus.com/documents/clutter_tutorial/0.9/docs/tutorial/html/sec-stage-widget.html which is in C, it works perfectly well but translating it to python ( https://gist.github.com/1759658 ) doesn't work at all.

By not working, I mean stage does not fire "button-press-event"

Comment: I think you have to run the GTK main loop instead of creating your own main loop and running that.

Comment: Tried that; Doesn't work. Tried both Clutter main loop and Gtk main loop but it didn't help. Also, I think post Gtk3 this is how we run the main loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the fact that `GtkClutter.init()` must be called before `Gtk.init()` and `Clutter.init()`, but the latter two are called upon import of the Gtk and Clutter packages.

Importing the packages like this seems to make your example work:

```
from gi.repository import GtkClutter
GtkClutter.init([])
from gi.repository import Clutter, GObject, Gtk
```